# How to show tabBarController when presenting new ViewController when button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, completionhandler

I have a activityfeedVC. If the user click a tableViewCell then an activityVC is shown. In this VC I have a "Back" button. When this is clicked I want to return to the previous view controller. I'm able to achieve this, but Im not able to show the tabBarController. Im using the completion handler, but something is wrong. Hope you can help.

```
import UIKit

class activityVC: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func backBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        // Navigates back
        let feedVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "feedVC")

        func completionHandler() {
            // show the tabBarController - NOT WORKING
            feedVC?.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
            print("tabBarController shown")
        }

        present(feedVC!, animated: false, completion: completionHandler)



    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }



}
```

I guess I should use the UINavigationBar instead of my customer navigation... maybe that is easier, even though I don't have many Views that needs this functionality...

Comment: did you debug if any of these are nil when you set the value `feedVC?.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false`

Comment: Also in your storyboard is `"feedVC"` the tabBarController or the activity view controller. you need to link to TabBarController if that is available in the storyboard. Another way to do this would be to just dismiss the current view controller instead of loading the other view controller on tapping back button if its being presented modally

Comment: Its not presented modally, so that don't work.  The tabBarController is created programatically in a class CustomTabBarController. Are you saying that rather than present the UIViewController I should present the CustomTabBarController?

Comment: Yes! Otherwise the TabBarController could be nil maybe why you are not seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you pushing activityVC onto the view controller stack? If so, you can simply pop activityVC when the user hits the back button.

```
class activityVC: UIViewController {

   @IBAction func backBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
      self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
   }
}
```